# How to know the decode type of a file that download from a website？

Tags: python-3.x, file, encoding

I meet a problem in my work, I am try to read a .doc file by using **python3**

**but I get an error:**

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'gb2312' codec can't decode byte ....: illegal multibyte sequence
```

I try many decode types, utf-8, GBK, utf-16... But every decode type gives me same result, all of them are Garbled, but I can open the file normally by  Microsoft Word , and all information in the file display well, I guess the file uses a decode type that me don't know or something is wrong? Can you give me some advice in this situation?

Thank you for your reading!

Comment: I find something is wrong, the way to open doc file different with the way open the txt file, we should to use some libraries in python3.

Comment: A .doc file is Microsoft Word **Binary** File Format which is possibly why Microsoft Word opens it OK.

Answer (score 0):

There is no sure method to detect what type of encoding is used, but luckily there is a [chardet](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/chardet) library, which can do it pretty well.

```
import chardet
chardet.detect(my_undecoded_string)//for example {'encoding': 'UTF-8', 'confidence': 1.0}
```

Look [here](http://chardet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html) for more examples of usage.

Comment: Thank your answer, maybe this will help others, my problem isn't the encoding type of a file....